# spring MVC - request mapping jsp files

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm refactoring old page. There are some JSP pages directly in WEB PAGES directory (Netbeans). I want that all *.jsp requests goes thru Sping MVC. So I've got controller with @RequestMapping like :

```
  @RequestMapping(value={ "/kontakt.do", "/kontakt.jsp"})
```

There is kontakt.jsp file in WEB-INF/jsp. There is also  kontakt.jsp file directly in WEB PAGES which I want to delete.

In web.xml I've got:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>universe</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>universe</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>      
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

So I suppose all *.jsp is supported by spring mvc now. Important part of universe-servlet is:

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
               location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/resources/"
               cache-period="10000" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/jsp/*"
               location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/jsp/"
               cache-period="10000" />



<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

so Spring will search for jsp file in WEB-INF/jsp/ and this is done. My controller got:

```
   @RequestMapping(value={ "/kontakt.do", "/kontakt.jsp"})
public String showPage(Model model){
    System.out.println("################################# JEST OBSŁUGA JSP ZE SPRINGA!");
    return "kontakt";
}
```

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Universe/WEB-INF/jsp/kontakt.jsp]

The problem is that if I request localhost/Universe/kontakt.do or localhost/Universe/kontakt.jsp I've receive in Tomcat logs:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Universe/WEB-INF/jsp/kontakt.jsp]

When I've removed part :

```
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

from:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>universe</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>      
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

kontakt.do works, but kontakt.jsp reads old file kontakt.jsp from web pages directory. What is problem?

Comment: Clean tomcat directory and check again.

Comment: nothing changed